# VueJS: Store objects in array not realy working

Tags: vue.js

i want to add some objects (firstname,lastname) in an array.
Here you can see my code:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    user: {
        firstname: null,
        lastname: null
      },
      formdata: {
        users: []
      }
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.formdata.users.push(this.user);
    }
  }
})



<div id="app">
    Firstname:
    <input class="input" type="text" v-model="user.firstname" />
    Lastname:
    <input class="input" type="text" v-model="user.lastname" />

    <button @click.prevent="add()" class="button is-primary">Add</button>
    <p>Debug: {{formdata}}</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cz1so0mw/

The problem is, that all entries will be overridden by input a new entry.
Can someone tell me, where the problem is?

Greetz
Tola

Comment: You're using the same object in multiple positions of the array so changes are reflected everywhere. Use a new object to fix: `this.formdata.users.push(Object.assign({}, this.user))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the same user object is different positions, so every time you make changes are reflected every where. So for that, what you have to do is, copy the user object to another object and then push that to the formdata array as below:

`this.formdata.users.push(Object.assign({}, this.user))`

Generally Object.assign() method is used to copy the values and properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It invokes getters and setters since it uses both [[Get]] on the source and [[Set]] on the target.

And it returns the target object which has properties and values copied from the target object.

Syntax:

`Object.assign(target, ...sources)`